# Subversion - What is the purpose of txn-protorevs

Tags: linux, svn

I have a Subversion server and into one of the Subversion repositories, I got this directory under the **db** directory:

```
txn-protorevs
```

which contains the following files for me

```
119M    1-4.rev
0       1-4.rev-lock
```

What is the purpose of this directory inside an SVN repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to understand the `db` directory, you should probably read through the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure) which SVN uses to implement FSFS, which has comments that go into extensive detail of how the pieces fit together.  In brief, here is what the files are

```
txn-protorevs/      Subdirectory containing transaction proto-revision files
    <txnid>.rev       Proto-revision file for transaction <txnid>
    <txnid>.rev-lock  Write lock for proto-rev file
```

And here is what a proto-revision file does

> The prototype rev file is used to store the text representations as
>   they are received from the client.  To ensure that only one client is
>   writing to the file at a given time, the "rev-lock" file is locked for
>   the duration of each write.